# Delphi XE2 - Return system locale in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, locale, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a Delphi XE2 FireMonkey app which I'm running on Win32 and MacOSX.  I want to return the current system locale (e.g. en_GB) the app is running on whether this is Win32 or MacOSX.  Is there a FireMonkey class/property that will provide this, maybe similar to TOSVersion?  Or other way of retrieving it?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [TPlatform.GetCurrentLangID](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Platform.TPlatform.GetCurrentLangID) property

Check this sample

```
uses
  FMX.Platform;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Platform.GetCurrentLangID);
end;
```

Comment: FYI, this function doesn't work with XE2... it's always return 'en'

Comment: Works as expected with XE4